# Rails each method with changing html (bootstrap carousel)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm trying to figure out a solution for Bootstrap 3's carousel in Rails 4.

I've got this:

```
  <li> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
    <%= image_tag @gallery.images[0].photo.url(:thumb), class: 'img-responsive' %>
  </a></li>
  <li> <a id="carousel-selector-1">
    <%= image_tag @gallery.images[1].photo.url(:thumb), class: 'img-responsive' %>
  </a></li> 


 ...etc...
```

I'm looking for an each type method that would account for a variable number of images in a gallery.

Something where the first photo looks like this:

```
  <li> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
    <%= image_tag @gallery.images[0].photo.url(:thumb), class: 'img-responsive' %>
  </a></li>
```

And those after it look like:

```
<li> <a id="carousel-selector-1">
    <%= image_tag @gallery.images[1].photo.url(:thumb), class: 'img-responsive' %>
  </a></li> 
.......
```

With each number increasing by one for each photo of course.

Thanks for the help!

**SOLUTION**

Thank you kindly creativereason!

Heres what worked:

```
<% @gallery.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
  <li> <a id="carousel-selector-<%=index%>" class="<%= 'selected' if index == 0%>">
    <%= image_tag image.photo.url(:thumb), class: 'img-responsive' %>
  </a></li>
  <% end%>
```

And if anyone is searching for a solution for .carousel-inner div (pretty much the same):

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
            <% @gallery.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
                <div class="item <%= 'active' if index == 0%>" data-slide-number="<%= index %>">
                  <%= image_tag image.photo.url(:large), class: 'img-responsive' %>
                </div>
            <% end%>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<% @gallery.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
  <li> <a id="carousel-selector-<%=index%>" class="<%='selected' if index == 0%>">
    <%= image_tag image.photo.url(:thumb), class: 'img-responsive' %>
  </a></li>
  <% end%>
```

Revised: because I didn't notice the selected difference in the `li` tag. Now I'm using `each_with_index`

Comment: Its telling me that selected is undefined. Any ideas? Will keep playing around.

Comment: Try ticks around selected and it should work, was thinking that could be a problem but wasn't in a place to double check the syntax before.